# Trie data structuring

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm making a trie and I need someone to tell me what's wrong with this code:

```
typedef struct node
{
 struct node *letters[26]={0};

} node;
```

I want to make it so that in every reference of a node struct, the pointers are all null...
Your help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you could go with the simple approach.**

You can create an  function,which will create and initialize all pointer with `NULL` then return `node` object.

**Could be as below.**

```
Node* GetMeANode()
    {
        //Create an object of Node structure here.
        //initialize all pointer with `NULL` 
        // Return it.
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't initialize a type. You can only initialize objects

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *letters[26];
} node;

node mynode = {0}; /* {{0}}  or even {{0, 0, 0, 0, ...}} */
```

Comment: Note that the `{0}` is the universal zero-initializer. It works for everything: `int foo = {0}; double bar = {0}; char list[100][10] = {0};`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize members of structs like that, but you can initialize them at instantiation time, or write an initializing function:

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
  struct node *letters[26];
} node;

void initNode(node * n) { memset(n->letters, 0, 26 * sizeof(node *)); }

void foo()
{
  /* aggregate initialization, efficient */
  node n = { 0, 0, 0, /* 26 times */ };

  /* helper function */
  node m;
  initNode(&m);
}
```

(If this were C++0x, you *could* initialize struct members in the default constructor's base initializer list, even arrays.)